# Are viruses technically organisms, or not?

Tags: microbiology, virus, virology, definitions, classification

**Are** ***viruses*** **technically** ***organisms*** **or not?**

A quick *[Google search query](https://www.google.com/search?&q=are%20viruses%20organisms?)* for the term; `are viruses organisms?`, reveals various conflicting and somewhat inconclusive arguments & opinions from a range of sources. *(Examples provided below).*

---

*Note: These answers are mostly opinion-based and inconclusive; falling short of the Stack Exchange community's quality control standards.*

---

*Let me be clear: I am not seeking opinions, or debate; but rather definitive answers supported by facts.*

---

> **Wikipedia | Organism.**
>   The most common argument in support of *viruses* as living *organisms* is their ability to undergo *evolution* and *replicate* through self-assembly...
>   Some scientists argue that *viruses* neither *evolve*, nor *self- reproduce*.
>   ***~*** *https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organism*
>
> **Encyclopedia of Life | What is a Virus?**
>   A *virus* is a microscopic *organism* that can replicate only inside the cells of a host *organism*...
>   *Viruses* infect all types of *organisms*, including *animals* and *plants*, as well as *bacteria* and *archaea*.
>   ***~*** *http://eol.org/info/458*
>
> **Virology Blog | Are Viruses Living?**
>   Therefore, *viruses* are not living things...
>   So technically speaking they are non- living *organisms*.
>   ***~*** *http://www.virology.ws/2004/06/09/are-viruses-living/*
>
> **Popular Science | Are Viruses Alive? New Evidence Says Yes.**
>   *Viruses* seem to carry out only one life process, *reproduction*, but even then, individual *viruses* don't carry *[translational machinery](http://eol.org/info/458?con=&dom=pscau&src=syndication)*, namely, the *proteins* needed to read their *DNA* and *RNA* and build new *viruses*. They invade a *cell* and hijack its *genetic tools* to do it for them...
>   But within the last decade, *developments in virology* have started to reveal more and more that *viruses might in fact be alive*...
>
> One was the *[discovery of mimiviruses](http://www.nature.com/scitable/topicpage/discovery-of-the-giant-mimivirus-14402410?con=&dom=pscau&src=syndication)*; *giant viruses* with large *genomic libraries* that are even bigger than some *bacteria*. (To put this in perspective, some *viruses*, like the *Ebola virus*, have as few as *seven genes*.) Some of these *giants* have *genes* for the *proteins* that are required for *translation*—those *readers of DNA and RNA* that in turn *build new viruses*...
>   This throws the lack of *translational machinery argument* for classifying them as nonliving on its head.
>   ***~*** *http://www.popsci.com.au/science/medicine/are-viruses-alive-new-evidence-says-yes,409690*
>
> **Science Daily | Virus.**
>   A *virus* is a microscopic *particle* that can infect the *cells* of a biological *organism*... 
>   At the most basic level, *viruses* consist of *genetic material* contained within a protective *protein coat* called a *capsid*; the existence of both *genetic material* and *protein* distinguishes them from other *virus*-like *particles* such as *prions* and *viroids*... 
>   It has been argued extensively whether *viruses* are living *organisms*...
>
> Most *virologists* consider them *non-living*, as they *do not* meet all the criteria of the *generally accepted definition* of *life*...
>   They are similar to obligate intracellular *parasites* as they lack the means for *self-reproduction* outside a *host cell*, but unlike *parasites*, *viruses* are generally not considered to be true living *organisms*...
>   A primary reason is that *viruses* do not possess a *cell membrane* or *metabolise* on their own - characteristics of all living *organisms*.
>   ***~*** *https://www.sciencedaily.com/terms/virus.htm*

Comment: @Remi.b Thankyou. It is worth linking, however; not the same question. Please don't report it as a duplicate. Cheers.

Comment: @tjt263 Can you explain how this question is different?

Comment: it is the same question, hence you've linked to sites that ask *are viruses alive?*

Comment: If you consider the definition of an organism to be 'something alive', they're the same question; if not, they're not.

Comment: So, if you think about where organism actually came from, *organization*, the virus is actually quite a very organized little compartment of stuff (without going into details). There are elements that have to cooperate within the actual virus to get anything done, thus, I would qualify that **yes** viruses are organisms. You wouldn't consider something like a prion or a viroid an organism, however, because on their own there's really just one part with no interdependencies.

Comment: Definitive suggests by definition. By definition, no. Fact- a virus is not an organism by definition. If the definition changes to include viruses, then yes. But for functional purposes, we speak english- which means utilizing the definition of words. The reason why a virus is not an organism is because it requires a host organism for replication. DNA is also not an organism.